# Unity door open and close

Tags: unity-game-engine

The door problem is that I want to make the door open more with each mouse click on it. After I click 5 times it should move back in the opposite direction, till it is closed.

```
if (i < 5)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 1080);
        i++;
    }
}

if (i >= 5)   
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        transform.Rotate(-Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 1080);
        i--;
    }

}
```

So this code has a problem and I don't know where. I think it's in the third `if` because it doesn't do the opposite direction(closing).

Comment: does it give an error or just not work? the 3rd if could be an `else if`. Also, your code decrements after closing and will be stuck in an open/close cycle...maybe change i>=5 to i<10 and make i-- to i++

Comment: it works fine till the 4th click that its open. then it dont go the opposite direction for closing.

Comment: I will assume that the `i` is initialized for 1 ?

Comment: no, its intializes as 0.

Comment: You need another variable or something. Everytime it gets to 5, it will decrement i by 1 and then go through the first check which will send it back up again. It's an endless back and forth loop.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to close the door after 4th click and the door should move in opposite direction

Try this:

```
//declare this var as a flag
bool inc = true;


if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    if(inc)
    {
     transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 1080);
     i++; 
    }
    else
    {
     transform.Rotate(-Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 1080);
     i--;
    }

 }


 if(i==0)
 {
   inc = true;
 }
 if(i==5)
 {
   inc = false; 
 }
```

Or instead of `-Vector3.up`, you can use `Vector3.down`.

**EDIT**: made change according to setting `i` as `4`

Comment: well, thank you all for the response, and I tried that but the problem is that i goes down to 4 and then it doing the first if.

Comment: @ZannikosCh fixed it try now

Comment: Deleted my answer since this one makes use of the bool idea I was going for in less code.